# Не билдится юнити проект для Android

Tags: android, unity3d

[![Я делаю тестовый проект для практики навыков, недавно установил версию для андроид игр и столкнулся с проблемой распаковки апк проекта, дело в том что вроде бы всё установилось нормально но в итоге после того как билд закончился появляется ошибка из за которой я не могу нормально создать проект, я пробовал указывать SDK из андроид студио, смотрел много форумов и в итоге и нашел решение

вот ошибка из консоли

```
CommandInvokationFailure: Gradle build failed. 
D:\unty\2022.3.15f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\OpenJDK\bin\java.exe -classpath "D:\unty\2022.3.15f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\Tools\gradle\lib\gradle-launcher-7.2.jar" org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain "-Dorg.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4096m" "assembleRelease"

Environment Variables:
SHIM_MCCOMPAT = 0x810000001
PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE = AMD64
AMPLITUDE_API_KEY_YELLOWBUCKET_DEV = 48835b4d1f5e342aefe5f016324d296a
BURST_ANDROID_MIN_API_LEVEL = 22
DriverData = C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\DriverData
USERDOMAIN = DESKTOP-TCJ95LS
CommonProgramFiles(x86) = C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files
COMPUTERNAME = DESKTOP-TCJ95LS
DEBUG_ENV_VAR = UnityHub
LOGONSERVER = \\DESKTOP-TCJ95LS
AMPLITUDE_TOKEN_GREENBUCKET_PROD = yyzPzalJDwrQcYNuOZam0bhKb26WyyhK
PUBLIC = C:\Users\Public
ProgramData = C:\ProgramData
SESSIONNAME = Console
AMPLITUDE_TOKEN_YELLOWBUCKET_PROD = Ph-837Q6GNodAkyc2MRkxVPUcjlIET4d
NVIDIAWHITELISTED = 0x01
ALLUSERSPROFILE = C:\ProgramData
SystemRoot = C:\Windows
windir = C:\Windows
AMPLITUDE_API_KEY_REDBUCKET_DEV = 46b8b46515e7632fc42a504b72e05fd0
ProgramFiles(x86) = C:\Program Files (x86)
ProgramW6432 = C:\Program Files
OS = Windows_NT
ANDROID_NDK_ROOT = D:\unty\2022.3.15f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\NDK
PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER = Intel64 Family 6 Model 42 Stepping 7, GenuineIntel
HEAP_CLIENT_TOKEN_STAGING = 3786794399
HOMEPATH = \Users\PC1
FPS_BROWSER_USER_PROFILE_STRING = Default
AMPLITUDE_TOKEN_REDBUCKET_DEV = U4PSN7S7PuYVRODivvdcFwbu8R6IHGqa
CHROME_CRASHPAD_PIPE_NAME = \\.\pipe\crashpad_11176_CQBOJJTFJXAUEDUT
PROCESSOR_LEVEL = 6
JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS = -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
CommonProgramFiles = C:\Program Files\Common Files
JAVA_HOME = D:\unty\2022.3.15f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\OpenJDK
USERDOMAIN_ROAMINGPROFILE = DESKTOP-TCJ95LS
TEMP = C:\Users\PC1\AppData\Local\Temp
CommonProgramW6432 = C:\Program Files\Common Files
AMPLITUDE_TOKEN_YELLOWBUCKET_DEV = wKi8foVigDditGFvmZewRFWsEbX9Y0YO
AMPLITUDE_API_KEY_GREENBUCKET_DEV = 3ded2a762163603391a425f688f990c8
AMPLITUDE_API_KEY_REDBUCKET_PROD = ca12bb461ea96f9bdf5df4ded7d52994
envContainerTelemetryApiCmdLine = -st "C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NvContainer\NvContainerTelemetryApi.dll"
HOMEDRIVE = C:
AMPLITUDE_API_KEY_STAGING = 83ee04fccc67e4fcc7dd527c4c6f1e21
USERNAME = PC1
AMPLITUDE_API_KEY_YELLOWBUCKET_PROD = e03a9bbe92dc38a88cdb068d24c65b46
PATHEXT = .COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC
AMPLITUDE_TOKEN_REDBUCKET_PROD = QqyoFpcWPi7V17p80_46CF6-sNGRGbHo
NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS = 4
AMPLITUDE_TOKEN_GREENBUCKET_DEV = 84H2gMm_FJzhr3mBaX1lM1JVukmCM7d9
AMPLITUDE_DEPLOYMENT_KEY_RED_BUCKET_DEV = client-wbjHYrmeSR87GmWOE7LDpf7sUySOIKHm
PSModulePath = C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules;C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules
AMPLITUDE_API_KEY_GREENBUCKET_PROD = c86fea37a9e1d3f0878b96e15b111c7c
ComSpec = C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe
ORIGINAL_XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP = undefined
PROCESSOR_REVISION = 2a07
AMPLITUDE_DEPLOYMENT_KEY_RED_BUCKET_PROD = client-zH8Y7OK1i331EKuG77C6UxN8ygcM6LzS
TMP = C:\Users\PC1\AppData\Local\Temp
SystemDrive = C:
AMPLITUDE_API_KEY = 28f3cae0b33b8b3702120c9ed1a935aa
envContainerTelemetryApiCmdLineX86 = -st "C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\NvContainer\NvContainerTelemetryApi.dll"
FPS_BROWSER_APP_PROFILE_STRING = Internet Explorer
SENTRY_ACCESS_TOKEN = 3df78d9e53f8456aa90fbae044ce1a6261421ab1d0014674bc2e933477289017
HEAP_CLIENT_TOKEN = 1717415662
APPDATA = C:\Users\PC1\AppData\Roaming
Path = C:\Program Files\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Users\PC1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Scripts\;C:\Users\PC1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\;C:\Users\PC1\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;;C:\Users\PC1\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin
ProgramFiles = C:\Program Files
LOCALAPPDATA = C:\Users\PC1\AppData\Local
USERPROFILE = C:\Users\PC1
WOOTRIC_CLIENT_TOKEN = NPS-aa8be4c3


stderr[
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':unityLibrary:mobilenotifications.androidlib:generateReleaseRFile'.
> Failed to install the following Android SDK packages as some licences have not been accepted.
     platforms;android-33 Android SDK Platform 33
  To build this project, accept the SDK license agreements and install the missing components using the Android Studio SDK Manager.
  Alternatively, to transfer the license agreements from one workstation to another, see http://d.android.com/r/studio-ui/export-licenses.html
  
  Using Android SDK: D:\unty\2022.3.15f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 9s
]
stdout[
WARNING:We recommend using a newer Android Gradle plugin to use compileSdk = 33

This Android Gradle plugin (7.1.2) was tested up to compileSdk = 32

This warning can be suppressed by adding
    android.suppressUnsupportedCompileSdk=33
to this project's gradle.properties

The build will continue, but you are strongly encouraged to update your project to
use a newer Android Gradle Plugin that has been tested with compileSdk = 33
Checking the license for package Android SDK Platform 33 in D:\unty\2022.3.15f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK\licenses
Warning: License for package Android SDK Platform 33 not accepted.
]
exit code: 1
UnityEditor.Android.Command.WaitForProgramToRun (UnityEditor.Utils.Program p, UnityEditor.Android.Command+WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg) (at <033353fa2720456c86cab3271f470887>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.Command.Run (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo psi, UnityEditor.Android.Command+WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg) (at <033353fa2720456c86cab3271f470887>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.Command.Run (System.String command, System.String args, System.String workingdir, UnityEditor.Android.Command+WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg) (at <033353fa2720456c86cab3271f470887>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.AndroidJavaTools.RunJava (System.String args, System.String workingdir, System.Action`1[T] progress, System.String error) (at <033353fa2720456c86cab3271f470887>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.GradleWrapper.Run (UnityEditor.Android.AndroidJavaTools javaTools, Unity.Android.Gradle.AndroidGradle androidGradle, System.String workingdir, System.String task, System.Action`1[T] progress) (at <033353fa2720456c86cab3271f470887>:0)
Rethrow as GradleInvokationException: Gradle build failed
UnityEditor.Android.GradleWrapper.Run (UnityEditor.Android.AndroidJavaTools javaTools, Unity.Android.Gradle.AndroidGradle androidGradle, System.String workingdir, System.String task, System.Action`1[T] progress) (at <033353fa2720456c86cab3271f470887>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.Tasks.BuildGradleProject.Execute (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context) (at <033353fa2720456c86cab3271f470887>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessRunner.RunAllTasks (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context) (at <033353fa2720456c86cab3271f470887>:0)
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr, Boolean&)
```

Comment: Вы не приняли лицензию SDK. Warning: License for package Android SDK Platform 33 not accepted.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39760172/you-have-not-accepted-the-license-agreements-of-the-following-sdk-components